# Function inputting all values into a matrix

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix

I am having trouble with my function.  When I call the function, it only seems to have looped through first value in my for loop and does not continue to fill my matrix.  Here is the code.  The output should be a matrix filled with 1's.

```
 binfunction <- function(y) { #Set up a function that takes a vector input and puts the elements into bins
  L <- length(y)
  x <- c(0, cumsum(y))
  U <- runif(1, min = 0 , max = sum(y))
  for(i in 1:L) {
   if(x[i] <= U && x[i+1] > U){
    return(i)
  }
 }
}


randomgraph <- function(n, beta) {
  mat <- matrix(0,n,n)
  mat[1,2] <- 1
  mat[2,1] <- 1
   for(i in 3:n) { #Loop that fills matrix
    degvect <- colSums(mat[ , (1:(i-1))])
    degvect <- degvect^(beta)
    j <- binfunction(degvect)
    mat[i,j] <- 1
    mat[j,i] <- 1
     return(mat)
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some test data.

Comment: That's all you need... Just put in an `n` and `beta`  value in `randomgraph`.  Say `n=10` and `beta=1`

Comment: aha. Move your `return()` function in your definition of `randomgraph` below the first `}`.

Comment: That works.  Should have seen that.  Thanks!